# Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default Set fielddata=true

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I am running elastic stack v 7.2.0 on kubernetes  and I am getting this error in the elasticsearh while accessing the metricbeat dashboard

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [host.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
```

My questions is If I have manually added the template and the dashboards, then why am I getting this error? With the template added should not the required mapping go inside the index? I saw some answers  which suggested to apply the required mapping explicitly. But then In this case how should i give the index name on which this mapping is to be applied as my metricbeat index would be created daily with each new date. How this explicit mapping will persist across all the metricbeat indices created with each date?
PUT /what-should-be-the-index-name/_mapping

Comment: Please add your Metricbeat configuration. That should automatically set up the index template, but with the name change something might be off. BTW you really want to use the keyword field and not enable fielddata, but that works automatically with the right mapping.

Comment: it could be one of the indices created before the mapping and index template was properly created exists. This would have a wrong mapping and could produce this error. You could also have mapping conflicts.